# Configure Jhipster with SQL Server Express and Liquibase

Tags: java, sql-server, jhipster, liquibase

I am trying  to configure SQL Server Express with Jhipster 7 and running into a error related to liquibase. The environment is Java 8.

This is a clean new project except that I have updated the jdbc connection string.

When I run `gradlew -x webapp` from terminal in Intellij I get

```
[.....]
2021-08-29 09:14:14.251 ERROR 12764 --- [   romeo-task-1] t.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready:
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: 
Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster:
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'jhi_user' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation. 
[Failed SQL: (8106) SET IDENTITY_INSERT jhi_user ON]
[....]
```

The connection to the datasbase is successful and the databasechange log table is created.

The table jhi_user is not created.

When logging into this table with Server Management Studio as the same user Jhipster is using I am able to create tables (so its not permission related).

**00000000000000000000_inital_schema.xml**

```
<changeSet id="00000000000000" author="jhipster">
    <createSequence sequenceName="sequence_generator" startValue="1050" incrementBy="50"/>
</changeSet>

<!--
    JHipster core tables.
    The initial schema has the '00000000000001' id, so that it is over-written if we re-generate it.
-->
<changeSet id="00000000000001" author="jhipster">
    <createTable tableName="jhi_user">
        <column name="id" type="bigint">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="login" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints unique="true" nullable="false" uniqueConstraintName="ux_user_login"/>
        </column>
        <column name="password_hash" type="varchar(60)"/>
        <column name="first_name" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="last_name" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="email" type="varchar(191)">
            <constraints unique="true" nullable="true" uniqueConstraintName="ux_user_email"/>
        </column>
        <column name="image_url" type="varchar(256)"/>
        <column name="activated" type="boolean" valueBoolean="false">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="lang_key" type="varchar(10)"/>
        <column name="activation_key" type="varchar(20)"/>
        <column name="reset_key" type="varchar(20)"/>
        <column name="created_by" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="created_date" type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="reset_date" type="timestamp">
            <constraints nullable="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="last_modified_by" type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="jhi_authority">
        <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <createTable tableName="jhi_user_authority">
        <column name="user_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="authority_name" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="user_id, authority_name" tableName="jhi_user_authority"/>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="authority_name"
                             baseTableName="jhi_user_authority"
                             constraintName="fk_authority_name"
                             referencedColumnNames="name"
                             referencedTableName="jhi_authority"/>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="user_id"
                             baseTableName="jhi_user_authority"
                             constraintName="fk_user_id"
                             referencedColumnNames="id"
                             referencedTableName="jhi_user"/>

    <addNotNullConstraint   columnName="password_hash"
                            columnDataType="varchar(60)"
                            tableName="jhi_user"/>
    
    <sql dbms="mssql">
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT jhi_user ON;
    </sql>
        
    <loadData
              file="config/liquibase/data/user.csv"
              separator=";"
              tableName="jhi_user">
        <column name="activated" type="boolean"/>
        <column name="created_date" type="timestamp"/>
    </loadData>
    
    <sql dbms="mssql">
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT jhi_user OFF;
    </sql>
       
    <dropDefaultValue tableName="jhi_user" columnName="created_date" columnDataType="${datetimeType}"/>
    <loadData
              file="config/liquibase/data/authority.csv"
              separator=";"
              tableName="jhi_authority">
        <column name="name" type="string"/>
    </loadData>

    <loadData
              file="config/liquibase/data/user_authority.csv"
              separator=";"
              tableName="jhi_user_authority">
        <column name="user_id" type="numeric"/>
    </loadData>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="jhipster" id="00000000000002" context="test">
    <createTable tableName="jhi_date_time_wrapper">
        <column  name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="jhi_date_time_wrapperPK"/>
        </column>
        <column name="instant" type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="local_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="offset_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="zoned_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
        <column name="local_time" type="time"/>
        <column name="offset_time" type="time"/>
        <column name="local_date" type="date"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

No apparent errors in db change log table either.
[image]

Running the gradle task `liquibaseUpdateSQL` shows the SQL and testing it directly on the database, the SQL is valid and creates a jhi_user table.

Running gradle task `liquibaseDiff` however generates this error:

```
liquibase.exception.CommandLineParsingException: The option --referenceUrl is required.
```

The only reference to referenceURL is in the build.gradle on the lines:

```
        diffLog {
        driver ""
        referenceUrl "hibernate:spring:nz.contoso.romeo.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy"
        url "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=romeo"
        username "user"
        password "supersecret"
        changeLogFile project.ext.diffChangelogFile
        //reference URL was here
        defaultSchemaName ""
        logLevel "debug"
        classpath "$buildDir/classes/java/main"
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: Well it looks that the initial schema migration is not compatible with SQL Server Express, you should modify it. Did you read https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/004_tip_using_ms_sql_server.html SQL Server is not very popular in JHipster community so it's possible that generated migrations are buggy

Comment: @GaëlMarziou the top of that page says support has been added so I don't need to take those manual steps anymore?

Comment: Even though, it does explain the differences that were needed to be implemented so you should review the generated migration with this in mind. Again, SQL Server is not widely used, so bugs can happen over time even if it was working perfectly at one time, I'm not even sure that JHipster CI runs tests on it.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I will read it (again) but also post inital_schema. I assume inital_schema is some sort of xml responsible for creating the jhi related tables? Interesting there is no complaints that the tables were not able to be created earlier in the stack trace.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Is there a way to trigger a creation of the jhi tables explicitly?

Comment: You should review the SQL generated by Liquibase from the xml. https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/generate-sql-update-schemas.html

Comment: So the SQL is not in a file in the project?

Comment: There's no SQL file anywhere, Liquibase interprets the XML and converts it to actionnable SQL. May I suggest you train yourself on Liquibase. You seem to discover it and you'll need to master it for your project

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Liquibase is not installed as part of Jhipster? I need to add it seperately? I am using gradle.

Comment: Liquibase is embedded within your spring boot application as a dependency but you can still install it as an external executable or use it through gradle plugin.